Configure base URL in kubb with tanstack-query v5
I am using kubb with tanstack-query v5 and sadly the example https://www.kubb.dev/examples/tanstack-query/react-query-v5 doesn't work, so I have no chance to find the issue I have, especially as this piece seems to have been changed recently.
The request is always made to localhost with the correct relative path set.
http://localhost:8081/correct/path/to/api/resource
// Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

On localhost:8081, my dev server is running.
So I am trying to configure the queryClient to set the base URL.
import axios from "axios";
import { QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://base.url.com",
    timeout: 15000
});

const client = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
            queryFn: async ({ queryKey }) => {
                console.log("Query Key:", queryKey); // NEVER LOGGED

                const { data } = await axiosInstance.get(queryKey[0] as string);
                return data;
            },
            staleTime: 0
        }
    }
});

export default client;

Then wrapping client in App (but this is working, because the request is made).
import { QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import client from "../api/client";

<QueryClientProvider client={client}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme.customTheme}>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
            <Stack>
                ...
            </Stack>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
</QueryClientProvider>

Is this the correct way of doing this with kubb? The web says so, but as "Query Key" is never logged and it seems this code never runs.
Older versions of kubb apparently had the base URL in their config, but this seems to be no longer the case.

In the latest version of Kubb you could use baseURL to override the default base. See https://www.kubb.dev/knowledge-base/base-url
